# What's the meaning of "you got it"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From [Friends S02E14](http://www.friendstranscripts.tk)

> INTERVIEWER: Alright, lets see if you're as good in person as you are on paper. Make me a salad.
>
> MONICA: A salad? Really I, I could do something a little more complicated if you like.
>
> INTERVIEWER: No, just a salad will be fine.
>
> MONICA: You got it.

The interviewer asked Monica to make a salad, and Monica said *you got it*, What's the meaning of it? Shouldn't it be *I got it* which means *I understood your words*?

Comment: "Now you got it" *could* mean "Now you understand", but that's not what it means in this context. As Maulik says, in this context, it means, "I'll take care of that for you." The phrase could be used any time someone is asking for a favor (not just a boss or commander). If you asked, "Could you check the mail while you're outside?" I might answer "Sure," but I could just as easily say, "You got it."

Comment: [You asked for it, you got it!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhD-oKJI69o) is also a catch phrase used by Toyota in their commercial ads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In TV dramas and movies, *you got it* is often used to mean *"I'll do as you ask"*. It's also common while taking an order from the boss/commander.

It is the response of a subordinate to their superior.

Answer (score 0):

"You got it" featured in TV advertisements for a chain of burger restaurants. A server is shown responding to a customer order by using that phrase. I see one implication as that the order is no sooner given than fulfilled.